# Pandas dataframe reverse sort on subsets using groupby

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with `names = ['id','t','metric_1','metric_2','metric_3']`. I am running some signal processing on each `grp in groupby('id')`. I need to reverse the time for another process that is taking in the entire dataframe and doing it's processing under the hood. Simply put, given a `grp`, I need to reverse the time column only, leaving all other columns intact, and all rows not in `grp` intact.

Input dataframe:

```
    id  t   metric_1    metric_2    metric_3
0   0   86  13.333  61.989  0.017444
1   0   87  13.333  61.993  0.017569
2   0   88  13.333  61.992  0.017711
3   0   89  13.333  61.998  0.017746
4   0   90  13.333  61.993  0.017871
5   1   32  13.333  61.964  0.018511
6   1   33  20.000  61.913  0.020058
7   1   34  20.000  61.864  0.022475
8   1   35  26.667  61.802  0.025995
9   1   36  33.123  61.563  0.032345
10  1   37  33.763  61.836  0.060189
11  2   2   13.333  61.964  0.018511
12  2   3   20.000  61.613  0.020058
13  2   4   20.000  61.164  0.027475
14  2   5   26.667  61.802  0.024995
15  2   6   33.333  61.736  0.030689
```

I would like to use an operation that yields a dataframe like this:

```
    id  t   metric_1    metric_2    metric_3
0   0   90  13.333  61.989  0.017444
1   0   89  13.333  61.993  0.017569
2   0   88  13.333  61.992  0.017711
3   0   87  13.333  61.998  0.017746
4   0   86  13.333  61.993  0.017871
5   1   37  13.333  61.964  0.018511
6   1   36  20.000  61.913  0.020058
7   1   35  20.000  61.864  0.022475
8   1   34  26.667  61.802  0.025995
9   1   33  33.333  61.736  0.030689
10  1   32  33.763  61.836  0.060189
11  2   6   13.333  61.964  0.018511
12  2   5   20.000  61.613  0.020058
13  2   4   20.000  61.164  0.027475
14  2   3   26.667  61.802  0.024995
15  2   2   33.333  61.736  0.030689
```

Comment: now i'm totally confused - do you want to sort / change values in `t` column where (`id == 1`) or not?

Comment: yes. The dataframe has id's from 0 to n where n is an integer. For each n, I want to reverse the corresponding `t` values. Each `id` may have a different number of `t` values so it needs to be done for each `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** sort / replace values in the `t` column, but only for those rows where `id == 0` ([as described in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474500/pandas-dataframe-reverse-sort-on-subsets-using-groupby#comment70155607_41474587)):

```
In [373]: df
Out[373]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0   0  86    13.333    61.989  0.017444
1   0  87    13.333    61.993  0.017569
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
3   0  89    13.333    61.998  0.017746
4   0  90    13.333    61.993  0.017871
5   1  86    13.333    61.964  0.018511
6   1  87    20.000    61.913  0.020058
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
8   1  89    26.667    61.802  0.025995
9   1  90    33.333    61.736  0.030689

In [374]: df.loc[df.id == 0, 't'] = df.loc[df.id == 0, 't'].sort_values(ascending=0).values

In [375]: df
Out[375]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0   0  90    13.333    61.989  0.017444
1   0  89    13.333    61.993  0.017569
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
3   0  87    13.333    61.998  0.017746
4   0  86    13.333    61.993  0.017871
5   1  86    13.333    61.964  0.018511
6   1  87    20.000    61.913  0.020058
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
8   1  89    26.667    61.802  0.025995
9   1  90    33.333    61.736  0.030689
```

**UPDATE:** for updated data sets

original DF:

```
In [363]: df
Out[363]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0   0  86    13.333    61.989  0.017444
1   0  87    13.333    61.993  0.017569
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
3   0  89    13.333    61.998  0.017746
4   0  90    13.333    61.993  0.017871
5   1  86    13.333    61.964  0.018511
6   1  87    20.000    61.913  0.020058
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
8   1  89    26.667    61.802  0.025995
9   1  90    33.333    61.736  0.030689
```

sorting complete rows:

```
In [364]: df.sort_values(['id','t'], ascending=[1,0])
Out[364]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
4   0  90    13.333    61.993  0.017871
3   0  89    13.333    61.998  0.017746
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
1   0  87    13.333    61.993  0.017569
0   0  86    13.333    61.989  0.017444
9   1  90    33.333    61.736  0.030689
8   1  89    26.667    61.802  0.025995
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
6   1  87    20.000    61.913  0.020058
5   1  86    13.333    61.964  0.018511   # <--
```

sorting values for two columns (`['id','t']`), replacing their values:

```
In [366]: df[['id','t']] = df[['id','t']].sort_values(['id','t'], ascending=[1,0]).values

In [367]: df
Out[367]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0   0  90    13.333    61.989  0.017444
1   0  89    13.333    61.993  0.017569
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
3   0  87    13.333    61.998  0.017746
4   0  86    13.333    61.993  0.017871
5   1  90    13.333    61.964  0.018511
6   1  89    20.000    61.913  0.020058
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
8   1  87    26.667    61.802  0.025995
9   1  86    33.333    61.736  0.030689  # <--
```

**OLD answer:**

IIUC you can simply sort your data by two columns:

```
In [349]: df.sort_values(['id','t'], ascending=[1,1])
Out[349]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
4   0  86    13.333    61.993  0.017871
3   0  87    13.333    61.998  0.017746
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
1   0  89    13.333    61.993  0.017569
0   0  90    13.333    61.989  0.017444
9   1  86    33.333    61.736  0.030689
8   1  87    26.667    61.802  0.025995
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
6   1  89    20.000    61.913  0.020058
5   1  90    13.333    61.964  0.018511
```

if you want to sort it as in your desired data set (replacing `t` column values):

```
In [357]: df[['id','t']] = df[['id','t']].sort_values(['id','t']).values

In [358]: df
Out[358]:
   id   t  metric_1  metric_2  metric_3
0   0  86    13.333    61.989  0.017444
1   0  87    13.333    61.993  0.017569
2   0  88    13.333    61.992  0.017711
3   0  89    13.333    61.998  0.017746
4   0  90    13.333    61.993  0.017871
5   1  86    13.333    61.964  0.018511
6   1  87    20.000    61.913  0.020058
7   1  88    20.000    61.864  0.022475
8   1  89    26.667    61.802  0.025995
9   1  90    33.333    61.736  0.030689   # 1 90 33.333 61.736 0.030689 as in your desired DF
```

Comment: Sorry @MaxU, I had the wrong dataframe in there. I made some edits.

Comment: @superhero, do you want to sort only `t` column values or complete rows? I mean would it be my first solution or the second one for your old data sets?

Comment: Only `t` but as a function of `id`. So, given the subset `id == 0` I want to reverse the column `t` so it reads descending instead of ascending but keeps all other columns as is, and all other rows where `id != 0` as is. Then, do the same thing for all subgroups as `groupby('id')`

Comment: @superhero, so you want to sort only those rows where `id == 0`, right?

Comment: @superhero, why do you have changed `t: 86 --> 90` in the row with index: `5` (where `id == 1`)?

Comment: You're a wizard. This does it: `df[['id','t']] = df[['id','t']].sort_values(['id','t'], ascending=[1,0]).values
`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reverse the 't' column leaving all other columns intact, you can try following code:

```
df.t=df['t'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Right, but it's more complicated. I want to reverse `t` for each `id`. Each `id` corresponds to a run of an experiment that lasts for n seconds where n is different every time. If I reverse just column `t` the time values will obviously be mismatched to their `id` benefactor.